# Java drawString parallel to a line

Tags: java, drawstring

How to draw string in java parallel to a line when I know line coordinates?
Below is my code so far, x1,y1 and x2,y2 represents the coordinates of line.
(text has to be parallel and to the center of the line)

```
g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.rotate(<WHAT TO PUT HERE>);
g.setTransform(at);
g.drawString("My Text", <WHAT TO PUT HERE> , <WHAT TO PUT HERE>);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you shouldn't use `setTransform` to overwrite the existing transform with a new one. The method's just intended to restore an earlier state to the `Graphics2D` object.

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right. What was I thinking... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research,

This is what I came up with

```
        //draw the line
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        //get center of the line
        int centerX =x1 + ((x2-x1)/2);
        int centerY =y1 + ((y2-y1)/2);

        //get the angle in degrees
        double deg = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(centerY - y2, centerX - x2)+ Math.PI);

        //need this in order to flip the text to be more readable within angles 90<deg<270
        if ((deg>90)&&(deg<270)){
            deg += 180;
        }

        double angle = Math.toRadians(deg);

        String text = "My text";
        Font f = new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(f);
        //get the length of the text on screen
        int sw =  fm.stringWidth(text);

        g.setFont(f);
        //rotate the text
        g.rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
        //draw the text to the center of the line
        g.drawString(text, centerX - (sw/2), centerY - 10); 
        //reverse the rotation
        g.rotate(-angle, centerX, centerY);
```

Thanks to @rocketboy and @resueman for the help

Answer (score 0):

> tan(theta) = slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
>
> theta = atan(slope)

that implies,[use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate%28double%29)

```
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta))
```

As for

```
g.drawString(String str, int x, int y)
```

x,y is the coordinate of the [leftmost character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) of your string.

Comment: So I do my code like:
 if (Math.abs(x2-x1)>0){
            double slope = (y2-y1)/Math.abs(x2-x1);
            double tan = Math.atan(slope);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(tan));}   Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, though you can do all that in a single statement :)